# 'Upright' meaning in "Please store upright below 25°C"

Tags: word-meaning

I read the sentence on the tag of a honey container.

> Please store **upright** below 25°C.

I looked it up. **Upright** as an adjective can mean:

> adj
>
> 1. vertical or erect
> 2. honest, honourable, or just

It seems the sense **just** is fit, but I'm not sure. What does it truly mean?

Comment: Definition 1 is literal; definition 2 is figurative.

Comment: Do you have trouble understanding why definition 1 makes sense in this context?

Comment: @Jasper, now I get it immediately after I saw the answer below. I just parsed the sentence wrongly. I feel a bit awkward now. :(

Comment: @Jasper, As a Chinese, I also didn't realize it at the first time, haha. I just thought about the second meaning "just". Please store it just below 25 degree.

Comment: @Jasper  In Chinese, the sentence bearing such a meaning, definitely should be splitted into 2 parts. Please store it upright and below 25 ... I think that linguistic difference caused the misunderstanding.

Comment: As a native speaker of British English, I don't think the sentence is particularly well-written: it doesn't parse easily and gives the impression of two adverbs smashed together with no regard to grammar. "Please store upright, and below 25C", "Please store below 25C and in an upright position", or even "Please store upright**,** below 25C" would have been better (in my opinion).

Comment: @马化腾 It should've been split in 2 parts in English as well. However, on a case or a bottle, there's often not much room for text. So they compress it to the point where a native can still figure it out and the rest has to rely on experience. If you're a bit short on experience, it leads to funny situations like these.

Comment: [Late here] The practical rationale is that honey stored at cool temperatures becomes slow flowing and so if stored other than upright you couldn't easily take it from the refrigerator, open the top and take some of the honey, reclose the container and put it back into the refrigerator again without difficulty, maybe needing to first bring it up to a useable or room temperature which wastes some of the effort of cooling it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It means the first one, or *in a vertical position, vertically* since it's used as an adverb in this example. That's the literal meaning. Basically, it's implying not to store it sideways. Also, just using common sense (aside from the dictionary meaning), it suggests to me not to store it upside down (if there is such a distinction).

Like this:
[image]

Not like this:
[image]
[image]
[image]

The [*just*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/just) in that definition refers to (M-W):

> *adjective*
>   2 a (1) : acting or being in conformity with what is morally upright or good : righteous • a just war

It is synonymous with "honest, honourable" in the definition you cited. It is **not** meant as

> *adverb*
>   2 a : by a very small margin : barely • just too late
>   b : immediately, directly • just west of here

Comment: Now I get it! Originally, I parsed the sentence incorrectly. I parsed it as: {Please store} [upright below 25°C], I thought "upright below 25°C" together means something related to temperature! The issue is due to my unfamiliarity of English conventions.

Comment: Yes, I could see why you thought "just" could fit. This is why we ask for context. :)

Comment: On the other hand, I think 'upright' here is more like an adjectival usage other than adverbial, because it denotes to store it in the state of being *upright*. Any thought?

Comment: @dan No, it's an adverb. As an adjective, the usage would be something like "Store in an upright position", modifying the noun "position". Here, it's modifying the verb "store", not the implied object of "store".